# Clarification regarding a peculiar answer to a simple probability question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, paradoxes

The king comes from a family of 2 children. What is the probability that the other child is his sister?

I acquired the correct answer $\frac{2}{3}$ which is boggeling my mind. Under any given circumstances prior to acknowledging this I would've naively, with great confidence, claimed that the correct answer evidently ought to be $\frac{1}{2}$. Is the result $\frac{2}{3}$ due to the fact that the other child already exists? Would it be correct to assess that had the other child not yet been born then the probability of it being female would've been $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: This sort of problem depends greatly on the exact phrasing.  Is, for example, the "king" the eldest male?  If so, then there are three equally likely cases:  $B_1G_1$, $G_1B_1$, $B_1B_2$.  We know that $G_1G_2$ is impossible because we know that at least one child was a boy.  In all three possible cases the king is $B_1$....in two of the three the other child is a girl, hence $\frac 23$.  If we are also told that the first child was a boy then we are down to two cases:  $B_1B_2$, $B_1G_1$ so, yes, the probability is now $\frac 12$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the is some kind of male-preference inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the result $\frac{2}{3}$ due to the fact that the other child already exists? Would it be correct to assess that had the other child not yet been born then the probability of it being female would've been $\frac{1}{2}$?

This is mostly right. There is also the issue of "ordering" of the two children; for simplicity, say, "first child" and "second child."

The problem (with answer $2/3$) as stated is asking for the probability that the *other* child is female, given that there are two children and *one* is male.

The other problem (with answer $1/2$) can be stated as asking for the probability that the *second* child is female, given that the *first* child is male.

If you consider the four outcomes MM, MF, FM, FF, you see that the first problem restricts the outcome space to MM, MF, FM, while the second problem restricts the outcome space to MM, MF.

Comment: Thank you, emphasising the difference between "other child" and "second child" made it clear to me.